# How I can set global variable inside function lua

Tags: iphone, lua, coronasdk

```
webView = nil
func()
function func()
              webView = native.newWebView( 0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
              webView:request( "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token="..twitter_request_token )
              webView:addEventListener( "urlRequest", webListener )

end
print(webView) -- webView = nil
```

How I can get `webView` outside `func`, which I change inside `func`. Help ne, please

Comment: don't initialise webView with `nil`. Instead use `webView = true` or `0` or `false` or `""`.

Comment: FYI-All Lua code is compiled as a function. Therefore, all global variables set by code are set inside a function.

Answer (score 2):

There is (almost) nothing wrong with your example. You need to make sure to call `func()` after you define it, but other than that it should work. For example, this outputs `something` for me:

```
webView = nil
function func()
  webView = "something"
end
func()
print(webView)
```

Yes, you can use explicit reference `_G.webView` inside the function, but there is no need to do that in your case.

If you still have an issue, it's probably because your `func()` is not executed when you think it is. Try to `print` the value of `webView` after it's assigned inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can just append _G in front of your variable in will work as global variable.

Everywhere you have to use your variable with _G.

For Ex:

```
_G.yourVaribalename=display.newText();
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont' need to declare variables, they are automatically global unless specified as local. And you can't call `func()` before func is defined. So try this:

```
function func()
    webView = native.newWebView( 0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    webView:request( "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token="..twitter_request_token )
    webView:addEventListener( "urlRequest", webListener )
end
func()
print(webView) -- webView will not be nil
```

In the above, `webView` is global so it will exist globally as soon as created within `func()`, and will continue to exist after `func()` returns.